# How can I detect more than one UUID of iBeacon source in Application class?

Tags: ibeacon-android

Using the pro library,

```
Region region = new Region("com.radiusnetworks.androidproximityreference.backgroundRegion",
                "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6", null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
```

It can only accept one UUID.
But if I want to detect more UUIDs, what can I do?

Comment: May I ask why do you need to detect more than one UUID?

Comment: maybe I have a list of ibeacon source so that I can take different actions depends on different UUID.

Comment: While a custom Android implementation can detect any number of UUID's, you may want to design your overall system with the infamous 20 UUID limit of iOS in mind - ie, use a small number of UUIDs for broad categories but do most of your differentiation with the major/minor fields within each UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternate constructor that lets you pass a list of Region objects.  Try this code:

```
Region region1 = new Region("com.radiusnetworks.androidproximityreference.backgroundRegion1",
            "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6", null, null);
Region region2 = new Region("com.radiusnetworks.androidproximityreference.backgroundRegion2",
            "E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0", null, null);
ArrayList regionList = new ArrayList<Region>();
regionList.add(region1);
regionList.add(region2);
regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, regionList);
```

See javadocs [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/pro/javadocs/com/radiusnetworks/proximity/ibeacon/startup/RegionBootstrap.html).